# Provide alert when two containers come in each other position range through CSS animation

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-animations

How can I find out when two containers collide with each other mainly using CSS animation?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: You should use some JsvsScript to follow the container positions using for example element.getBoundingClientRect()

Comment: Consider using [`IntersectionObserver`](//developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/IntersectionObserver).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementById("idvalue").getBoundingClientRect()` works for these types of problems. It gave the position of the element whose id is provided. So, we can write an if-else statement when both positions are the same to give an alert when collision happens.